# error accessing a file for Facebook upload

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, air

i am trying to upload a video to the users Facebook wall i have the FacebookMobile.uploadVideo in place and appears to to be fine but am getting the following error from facebook:

```
(#353) You must select a video file to upload.
```

i think the problem is in accessing the video file for some reason.

```
public function handleUpload(ev:TouchEvent)
{
   trace ("posting to facebook"+  accessCamera.filePath);
   var videoInfo:Object = new Object;   
   videoInfo.title = "test upload on FB api",
   videoInfo.description = accessCamera.filePath,
   videoInfo.fileName =  accessCamera.filePath;
   videoInfo.video = accessCamera.filePath;
   FacebookMobile.uploadVideo('me/videos', onComplete, videoInfo);
}

private function onComplete( result:Object, fail:Object ):void
{
    trace("facebook post onComplete called" );
    if (result)
    {
        //result.id is id of post that was just posted
        trace ("great");
    }
    else if (fail)
    {
        trace("post Failed");  
        trace('code: '+fail.error.code); 
        trace('message: '+fail.error.message);
        trace('type: '+fail.error.type); 
    }
}
```

`accessCamera.filepath` is the var where the video file is located on the device and looks like this when traced : `file:///mnt/sdcard2/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140304_105813.mp4`

Am I accessing the file correctly, does it need to be loaded by the app or is a path fine.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use the replace filePath=filePath.replace('file://','') but I am not sure f this will fix your issue

Comment: that did not help do i need to load the file in as3 first? thought i would just need to give the loaction of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is i was passing a string variable containing the file location into the params object and the FacebookMobile.uploadVideo requires either a fileReferance or byteArray.